# Как объединить обработчики событий, представленные как значения ключей в объектах

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть компонент react `Component` который содержит объект `ownedEventHandlers`с обработчиком события. При вызове компонента `Component` в него передается еще один объект `handlers` с обработчиками. Моя задача состоит в том, что бы объединить функционал колбеков, находящихся в объектах `ownedEventHandlers` и `handlers`.
Например в функции `mergeHandlers`

```
const handlers = {
onClick: (e) => do something else,
}

const Component = ({handlers}) => {

  const ownedEventHandlers = {
    onClick: (e) => do something,
  }

  const mergeHandlers = (ownedEventHandlers, handlers) => {
   функция должна объединить функционал колбеков.

     return {
       onClick: (e) => {
         выполнить функционал из колбека из объекта `handlers`
         выполнить функционал из колбека из объекта 
                                            `ownedEventHandlers`
       }
     }
  }
  return(
    <button {...mergeHandlers(ownedEventHandlers, handlers)}) />
      
}
```

Функция `mergeHandlers` должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
const mergeHandlers = (ownedEventHandlers, addedEventHandlers) => {
    const _ownedEventHandlers = { ...ownedEventHandlers };
    
    if (!addedEventHandlers || Object.keys(addedEventHandlers).length === 0) {
      return _ownedEventHandlers;
    }
    const keyAddedEventHandlers = Object.keys(addedEventHandlers);
    for (const handl in ownedEventHandlers) {
      if (ownedEventHandlers.hasOwnProperty(handl)) {
        for (let i = 0; i < keyAddedEventHandlers.length; i++) {
          if (handl === keyAddedEventHandlers[i]) {
// В этом месте нужно объединить функционалы двух обработчиков onClick
            console.log('нужно объединение');
          } else {
            _ownedEventHandlers[keyAddedEventHandlers[i]] = addedEventHandlers[keyAddedEventHandlers[i]];
          }
        }
      }
    }
    console.log('_ownedEventHandlers', _ownedEventHandlers);
    return _ownedEventHandlers;
  };
```

Есть вариант в исходном объекте с обработчиками ownedEventHandlers значением ключа делать функцию которая будет вызывать другие функции это го же события например так:

```
const ownedEventHandlers = {
    onClick: (e) => {
     (() => do something)()
    }
  }
```

и добавлять обработчики в неё, но не представляю как это сделать.
Прошу поделиться идеями по этому поводу.
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Не очень понятно, что вы хотите сделать. Можете дополнить вопрос и показать, как 2 компонента с обработчиками должны быть объеденены? Что значит вернуть объедененный объект? и вернуть куда, если это событие...

Comment: Компоненты в данном случае не объединяются. Есть универсальный компонент с собственными обработчиками. Мне нужно что бы в пропах можно было передать еще объект с обработчиками что бы дополнить собственные обработчики компонента.
Под "вернуть объединенный объект" я подразумеваю что нужно вернуть объект который будет содержать функционал собственных обработчиков компонента и функционал обработчиков которые были переданы в пропах.
Если ясности не внес, то подскажите. Я подумаю как еще исправить вопрос.

Comment: Можете, сделать код, что вы хотите видеть. Может так будет более понятно. Мол вот компонент1, это компонет2, вот универсальный, вот как то так передаем туда такие то данные, а тут надо что бы это вот так выглядело, вот такое вернулось... Думаю на примере кода с компонетами будет понятнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сообщество надейся а сам не бездельничай!!!
Вот и я решил свой вопрос.
Функция которая объединяет функционал обработчиков выглядит так:

```
const concatenatesEventHandlers = (ownedEventHandlers, addedEventHandlers) => {
    const _ownedEventHandlers = { ...ownedEventHandlers };
    if (!addedEventHandlers || Object.keys(addedEventHandlers).length === 0) {
      return _ownedEventHandlers;
    }
    const keyAddedEventHandlers = Object.keys(addedEventHandlers);
    for (const handl in ownedEventHandlers) {
      if (ownedEventHandlers.hasOwnProperty(handl)) {
        for (let i = 0; i < keyAddedEventHandlers.length; i++) {
          if (handl === keyAddedEventHandlers[i]) {
**Ниже в трёх строчках я создаю функцию которая по очереди вызывает обработчики**
            const concatFunc = (e) => {
              ownedEventHandlers[handl]();
              addedEventHandlers[keyAddedEventHandlers[i]](e);
            };
**Присваиваю функцию `concatFunc` обработчику в смёрженом объекте**
            _ownedEventHandlers[keyAddedEventHandlers[i]] = concatFunc;
          } else {
            _ownedEventHandlers[keyAddedEventHandlers[i]] = addedEventHandlers[keyAddedEventHandlers[i]];
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return _ownedEventHandlers;
  };
```

Возможно мой опыт будет кому то полезным.

Если у более опытных товарищей будут замечания по моему коду прошу высказаться. Для меня это важно.